# How do I use link download attribute in FF and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, download

After all of my research here and on other sites, I have arrived at the following code for saving some given text ("text" variable) with a given file name ("fileName" variable), but it only works perfectly in IE. Firefox downloads the file, but uses its own random name (like "G5QJNAr0"). And Chrome does nothing at all.

```
try {
    var blob = new Blob([text], {
         type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"
    });
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
         window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {
        var encodedData = encodeURI(text);
        var link = document.createElement("link");
        link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
        if ( 'URL' in window ) {
            link.setAttribute("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
            link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
            link.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(link);
        } else if ( 'webkitURL' in window ) {
            link.setAttribute("href", window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob));
        }
        link.click();
    }
} catch (e) {
    alert("Got error trying download text: " + e);
}
```

No browser results in alerting the Exception.

Chrome goes through all of the breakpoints I set and clicks the link at the end. But does absolutely nothing.

Can someone help me with the filename and no-response problems in FF and Chrome, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
```

change

```
var link = document.createElement("link");
```

to

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
```

Comment: Yes. Posted my results just while yours came in. Thanks. Why the removal of the target attribute setting? Unnecessary or problematic? It seems to work.

Comment: @user3020199 - my firefox sometimes wanted to popup a window - could've been other stuff causing that for me though

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the subtle difference for both browsers was the creation of a "link" inside of an anchor "a".

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
```

The above line makes it work.